# How to use doom-modeline in spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, mode-line

This might be a fairly stupid question but I simply can't figure it out.

I've been trying to install doom-modeline for spacemacs:
https://seagle0128.github.io/doom-modeline/#install

I've added the `use-package` stuff to the configuration file like this:

```lisp
...
   ;; configuration in `dotspacemacs/user-config'.
   dotspacemacs-additional-packages '((use-package doom-modeline
                                        :ensure t
                                        :init (doom-modeline-mode 1))
                                      (use-package all-the-icons))
   ;; A list of packages that cannot be updated.
   dotspacemacs-frozen-packages '()

...
```

Then I restarted spacemacs and it did install something. However, the modeline didn't change:

[image: my modeline]

It doesn't look like in the screenshots here: https://seagle0128.github.io/doom-modeline/#screenshots

Do I somehow have to activate it or something?

Comment: Did you try recompiling the spaceline? M-x spaceline-compile

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**:
I did not find a way to integrate it into the Spacemacs intended use of packages.

## Solution

Adding this snippet to my `dotspacemacs/user-config`:

```
(use-package doom-modeline
:ensure t
:init (doom-modeline-mode 1)
:config
;; Enable flashing mode-line on errors
(doom-themes-visual-bell-config)

;; Corrects (and improves) org-mode's native fontification.
(doom-themes-org-config)
)
```

## Drawback

- The packages `doom-modeline`is going to be delete and reinstalled at every Emacs startup when `dotspacemacs-install-packages 'used-only)` this option is set ( which I would recommend to avoid garbage ).

It seems Spacemacs does not support constructs like this`(use-package <package> :ensure t)`.

## Things tried

- Putting `doom-modeline` into `dotspacemacs-additional-packages`.

  - Including trying to add the configuration block I put into the `dotspacemacs/user-config` section.
  - Result: Configuration is not applied.
- Writing a custom layer and initializing `doom-modeline` in this layer.

  - Result: Configuration is not applied.

## References

- [How to integrate packages into the Spacemacs ecosystem](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/1538#issuecomment-317241460)
- [Remark: `(use-package <package> :ensure t)` not working](https://emacs-china.org/t/shrink-path-doom-modeline/15218/2)

Answer (score 0):

i've been all over the place with this , the issue with doom-modeline is that it gets removed as orphan caue if you require or use-package it duplicates it , look at the spacemacs-modeling layer..grep for doom-modeline.
The trick is this tell spacemacs modeline to use doom-modeline:

`dotspacemacs-mode-line-theme '(doom :separator-scale 1.5)`

and then just simply

`(doom-modeline-mode 1)`
in `(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()`

and it will never get removed again.
here's he doc:

```
   ;; Set the theme for the Spaceline. Supported themes are `spacemacs',
   ;; `all-the-icons', `custom', `doom', `vim-powerline' and `vanilla'. The
   ;; first three are spaceline themes. `doom' is the doom-emacs mode-line.
   ;; `vanilla' is default Emacs mode-line. `custom' is a user defined themes,
   ;; refer to the DOCUMENTATION.org for more info on how to create your own
   ;; spaceline theme. Value can be a symbol or list with additional properties.
   ;; (default '(spacemacs :separator wave :separator-scale 1.5))
```